# Select most recent year and most complete row by date R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a time series data where I'm trying to get the most recent valid response per ID. Here's my starting test dataset:

```
dta <- data.frame(
  uniqueID = c("950513","950513", "950513","951634","951634", "951634","951640","951640", "951640",
               "951641","951641", "951641","951646","951646", "951646","952732","952732", "952732",
               "952895", "952895", "952895","952909","952909", "952909","952910","952910", "952910",
               "952911","952911", "952911"),
  year = c(2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016,
           2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2014, 2015, 2016),
  var1 = c(2115, NA, 2115,NA, NA, NA, NA, 2903, NA, NA, 6040, 6040, 6103, 6103, 6268, 6511, 7101, 7101,
           7105, 7105, 7105,8901, 8520, 8901, 8540, 8540, NA, 8854, 2108, NA),
  var2 = c(2115, "", 2115,"", "", "", "", 2903, "", "", 6040, 6040, 6103, 6103, 6268, 6511, 7101, 7101,
           7105, 7105, 7105,8901, 8520, 8901, 8540, 8540, "", 8854, 2108, ""),
  var3 = c("turtle", "turtle", "turtle","", "tortoise","", "turtle", "", "", "", "turtle", "tortoise", 
           "tortoise", "tortoise", "", "", "turtle", "", "turtle", "tortoise", "turtle", "tortoise", "", "",
           "", "", "", "tortoise", "turtle", "tortoise"),
  var4 = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "yellow", "", "blue", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "red", "red", "", "",
           "", "", "", "pink", "", "", "", "", "")
)
```

I'm looking to have one per uniqueID where I'm getting the most recent (by year) response with most complete information for that ID for all columns var1-var4. Step-by step, here's what I'd like to do:

- Have one row of output per uniqueID
- By default, select most recent year(row) of response (responses are in var1 - var4)
- In the case where there is missing value or blank for the most recent year of response (var1-var4), ignore in favor of a different value in the same column for that ID, collapsing years when necessary. e.g. 2014&2015

Based on my test dataset, here's what i was hoping the dataset could end up looking like:

```
result <- data.frame(
  uniqueID = c("950513","951634","951640","951641","951646","952732","952895","952909","952910",
                       "952911"),
year = c("2016","2015","2015&2014","2016&2014", "2016&2015", "2016&2015", "2016&2014", "2016&2014", "2015&2014", "2016&2015" ),
var1 = c(2115,NA,2903, 6040, 6268, 7101, 7105, 8901, 8540, 2108),
var2 = c(2115,"", 2903, 6040, 6268, 7101, 7105, 8901, 8540, 2018),
var3 = c("turtle","tortoise", "turtle", "tortoise", "tortoise", "turtle", "turtle", "tortoise","", "tortoise"),
var4 = c("","", "yellow", "blue", "", "red", "red", "", "pink", "")
)
```

Alternatively, year can be split into multiple columns year1, year2.

I've tried a couple of different solutions using data.table but those typically focus either on most recent year, or most complete case, but not both. Happy to provide more clarification if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.

```
is_valid <- function(x){
  !(x == "" | is.na(x))
}
valid_x <- function(x){
  if(any(is_valid(x))){
    x[which(is_valid(x))]
  }
  else{
    ""
  }
}
result <- dta %>% 
  mutate(across(contains("var"), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(contains("var"), names_to="var", values_to="val") %>% 
  group_by(uniqueID, var) %>% 
  mutate(last_val = last(valid_x(val)), 
         last_year = max(year[which(val == last_val)])) %>%
  filter(year == last_year) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(uniqueID) %>% 
  mutate(last_year = paste(sort(unique(last_year[which(is_valid(last_val))]), decreasing=TRUE), collapse="&")) %>%
  select(-c(val, year)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from="var", values_from="last_val") %>% 
  rename("year" = "last_year")

result
# # A tibble: 10 x 6
# # Groups:   uniqueID [10]
#   uniqueID year      var1  var2   var3       var4    
#   <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>   
# 1 950513   2016      2115  "2115" "turtle"   ""      
# 2 951634   2015      NA    ""     "tortoise" ""      
# 3 951640   2015&2014 2903  "2903" "turtle"   "yellow"
# 4 951641   2016&2014 6040  "6040" "tortoise" "blue"  
# 5 951646   2016&2015 6268  "6268" "tortoise" ""      
# 6 952732   2016&2015 7101  "7101" "turtle"   "red"   
# 7 952895   2016&2014 7105  "7105" "turtle"   "red"   
# 8 952909   2016&2014 8901  "8901" "tortoise" ""      
# 9 952910   2015&2014 8540  "8540" ""         "pink"  
# 10 952911   2016&2015 2108  "2108" "tortoise" ""
```

Comment: thanks, this works fairly well but for not rows with NAs where I want to bring in multiple years. I want to collapse these as well into one row. any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: @st2coker I'm not sure exactly what you mean.  Can you explain a bit more?  Maybe provide an example?

Comment: my real dataset has NAs that are preventing rows from being collapsed into one row. so for example, the output is year 2018&2019 but still has both rows from each ID, instead of one row per id. as a workaround i could use this but just wanted to see if i could incorporate into original solution result2 %>% 
  group_by(uniqueID) %>% 
  summarise_all(funs(first(na.omit(.))))

Comment: Could you post some example data that exhibits the problem?